# How to convert .exe setup file to .scr file?

Tags: wpf

I am doing screen saver project so i want to convert project .exe file to scr file.

Comment: This is not a forum; __this is a questions and answer site, and I'm afraid your post isn't really a question, because [real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).__ [Please read the FAQ for more information.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: nothing is there to afraid on that question

Comment: i got doubt.that's y i asked that.

Comment: Well, it's a crappy question. Read the FAQ and the other link I posted above on how to write better questions.

Answer (score 3):

Just rename the file. A .scr file is identical in format to a .exe but by convention has the .scr extension. I expect that you can configure a WPF project to output a target with .scr extension which would save the renaming step..

Comment: i need step by step process could u please.

Comment: Step by step process to do what. It's very far from clear what you actually want to do.